# zend framework with load balancing

Tags: php, zend-framework, scalability, load-balancing

suppose I implemented my site using Zend Framework and then after some time scalability issue start to arise so we decide to implement some load balancing to solve it...

will the fact that I used zend framework would prevent me to implement load balancing in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

definitely not.

You can load balance zend framework applications easily.

you should be aware of session. if you are using session, load balancer should support sticky session.

Comment: or use database for session :-)